# Search if multiple values exist in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array 'iid_nn' which will contain ~ 50 values.

If iid_nn contains either 13652 or 39855, then var somevar = 'cabbages' else var somevar = 'carrots'.

If checking for one of those values I could do

```
if(iid_nn.indexOf(13652) >=0) {
    var somevar = 'cabbages';
} else if(iid_nn.indexOf(39855) >=0) {
    {var somevar = 'cabbages';
} else {
    var somevar = 'carrots';}
```

But can I do something like

```
if(iid_nn.indexOf(13652||39855) >=0) {
    var somevar = 'cabbages';
} else {
    var somevar = 'carrots';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either modify your `indexOf` conditional to be:

```
if (iid_nn.indexOf(13652) > -1 || iid_nn.indexOf(39855) > -1) {
```

Or you can try using [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
if (iid_nn.some(function(i) { return i === 13652 || i === 39855; }) === true) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can’t pass one value to `indexOf` that will cause it to search for multiple values. You can use the `||` operator normally, though:

```
var somevar;

if (iid_nn.indexOf(13652) >= 0 || iid_nn.indexOf(39855) >= 0) {
    somevar = 'cabbages';
} else {
    somevar = 'carrots';
}
```

And maybe create your own function to do it:

```
function containsAny(array, items) {
    return array.some(function (item) {
        return items.indexOf(item) !== -1;
    });
}

var somevar;

if (containsAny(iid_nn, [13652, 39855])) {
    somevar = 'cabbages';
} else {
    somevar = 'carrots';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check index of multiple values, you need to update your code to following. Additionally, you can default the value to carrots and then on condition update it.

```
var somevar = 'carrots';

if(iid_nn.indexOf(13652) >= -1 || iid_nn.indexOf(39855) >= -1) {
    somevar = 'cabbages';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is kind of wrong.

```
if(iid_nn.indexOf(39855)!=-1 || iid_nn.indexOf(13652)!=-1) 
{
    var somevar = 'cabbages';
} else {
    var somevar = 'carrots';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if((iid_nn.indexOf(13652) !=-1)||(iid_nn.indexOf(39855) !=-1)) {
    var somevar = 'cabbages';
} else {
    var somevar = 'carrots';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var iid_nn = [13652],
    somevar;
if (~iid_nn.indexOf(13652) || ~iid_nn.indexOf(39855)) {
    somevar = 'cabbages';
} else {
    somevar = 'carrots';
}
```